# How to delete Multiple rows in excel file using activex in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, activex

```
Activesheet.Rows.Item(1).Delete;
```

The above line will delete first row in the active excel sheet.

I want to delete multiple rows so I used the following line, but it did not work.

```
Activesheet.Rows.Item([1,2,5,64]).Delete;
```

Comment: Isn't that vba? Try `Activesheet.Rows("[1,2,5,64]").EntireRow.Delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a full Matlab approach you could try this out:

```
rows_to_delete = [1 2 5 64];

data = xlsread(file_path);
data(rows_to_delete,:) = [];

delete(file_path);
xlswrite(file_path,data);
```

Using Excel COM:

```
Activesheet.Rows('1, 2, 5, 64').EntireRow.Delete
```

or:

```
Activesheet.Range('1, 2, 5, 64').Rows.EntireRow.Delete
```

You could even try a more consistent notation, eventually, using `1:1, 2:2, 5:5, 64:64` instead of `1, 2, 5, 64`. But I always used the latter without problems in my code.

Comment: Is the spreadsheet protected? What is the current UsedRange of the sheet?

Comment: the current Used Range of the sheet :$A$1:$V$3877. I do not know if it is protected or not.

Comment: Open the sheet and see if you can edit it. If this is the case, we must search for more uncommon patterns of this error message.

Comment: Activesheet.Range('1:1, 2:2, 5:5, 64:64').Rows.EntireRow.Delete it worked. what should I do to make Activesheet.Range('1, 2, 5, 64').Rows.EntireRow.Delete works.

Comment: Probably only the extended notation works. I fear you have no choice but to use that one. Does it pose you a problem?

Comment: I can edit the sheet. do u have an resources for activeX in Matlab

Comment: The best you can do is to have a look at Excel Interop documentation, which is almost the same thing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=vs.140).aspx